# Static HTML not showing in "View Page Source" even though data was fetched by getStaticProps()

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

This is a 2-part question that is related (somewhat):

**Part I:** Rendering HTML output via `getStaticProps` in the "View Page Source" view.

For SEO reasons, I'd like my Next.js frontend application to return HTML output in the "View Page Source" view (in Google Chrome) instead of JSON.

I'm using `getStaticProps()` to return some data from my backend Django app. I built the same page and functionality in React Remix Run, and I CAN see my HTML output. However, I'd like this to render the full HTML (instead of JSON) in my Next.js app so that I don't have to rewrite the entire application in Remix.

Here's my code:

Next.js code

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const { slug } = context.params

    const product = await fetchProductDetails(slug)
    const otherProductsList = await fetchProducts()

    const error = product.error ? product.error : ''

    return {
        props: {
            product,
            otherProductsList,
            error
        },
        revalidate: 15
    }
}

// Functional component
const ProductDetails = ({ product, otherProductsList, error }) => {
    // my client side code...
    
    return (
       // my JSX code that displays the product data using {product.name}, 
       {product.price}, etc. 

       // The "View Page Source" view does not show this JSX element as an h1 tag. 
       // Instead, it shows all of the JSON being returned from the DB.
       <h1>{product.name}</h1>
    ) 
}
```

Example source code output shown in "View Page Source" view:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
      <meta name="next-head-count" content="2"/>
      <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/75fa4eff9b884fe2.css" as="style"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/75fa4eff9b884fe2.css" data-n-g=""/>
      <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/eafeef7863427731.css" as="style"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/eafeef7863427731.css" data-n-p=""/>
      <noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
      <script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-5cd94c89d3acac5f.js"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-dd2ed5d38a88a4b3.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-0f8b31729833af61.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-83d2e1974cccf08f.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-fa3d7135221d445a.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/885-9d94ce365372990b.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/341-e930103f26cccc8f.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/418-874816ac548e7a1e.js" defer="">

// LOTS OF JSON OUTPUT HERE - THIS SHOULD BE HTML INSTEAD

</script>
</html>
```

Any idea why Next.js is returning JSON in the "View Page Source" view instead of JSON despite using `getStaticProps()` to fetch the data?

NOTE: I also tried removing my `useEffect()` hook (which is currently used to handle "success" operations), and I'm still getting JSON output. Also to note, the HTML markup actually shows as expected in the Google Chrome Inspect window.

**Part 2:** Setting `<meta property>` tags in Next.js on the page level.

I am also trying to set `<meta property>` tags on the page level (every page has a different meta property) so that my thumbnails and title text can be accessed through link sharing on social media platforms. For example, if I copy a link to a product page from my Next.js application, and post it to my Twitter feed, Twitter should pull the product thumbnail, title, description, etc.

I already know what code to write to make this work, but as related to the above problem, these tags are not showing in "View Page Soruce".

Are these two problems related?

Comment: A page component using `getStaticProps` will generated the HTML at build time, and serve that HTML on each request. This means the `View Page Source` view should contain everything you're rendering in `ProductDetails`, assuming nothing gets rendered on the client-side only (from a `useEffect`, for instance). Could you provide a [mre] of the issue?

Comment: I figured it out. This issue was being caused by a HOC (Higher Order Component) I was using to check authentication on every page. The `props` argument (pageProps) being passed to the HOC should be passed to the return statement, which in this case, is the "wrapped component". You can find examples of this structure by searching Gogole.

Comment: For now, I have removed the HOC reference (as I don't need ti right now), and now the HTML for the dynamic content is rendering via `getStaticPRops` and `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: @RonB I can use some help. I am running into this same issue with META tags not working as expected in view-source. Can you please help me? What do I need to do?